# Is Lebesgue outer measure additive if one summand is Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $A$ is Lebesgue measurable and any $B$ bounded set disjoint with $A$, is $m^*(A \bigcup B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)$? I know that it is not true for arbitrary $A,B$ by Vitali non-measurable set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $A$ is measurable iff for every $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

$$m^*( T ) = m^*( A \cap T ) + m^*( A^c \cap T ).$$

Letting $T = A \cup B$, we get $m^*( A \cup B ) = m^*( A ) + m^*( B )$.